# Oracle DataReader Erroring on GetDateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datareader

I have a particular data row that is throwing this error when I try to read in a particular date column - "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime".

I'm pulling in several hundred rows of data and they all work except for this one row. I can pull in the other columns from this problematic row except for this one datetime column. I'm using an oracle data reader to fetch a datetime from the database, I can use the watch tool in Visual Studio examine the row I'm about to read in. Everything looks good in the watch tool - it sees the column I'm trying to read in as a datetime and has all of it's properties.

```
      while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var temp = new FCCondition();
                    temp.CaseID = reader.GetString(0);                      
                    temp.Statute = reader.GetString(1);
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
                        temp.DueDate = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
                        temp.HoursAssigned = reader.GetInt32(3);
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
                        temp.HoursCompleted = reader.GetInt32(4);
                    temp.JWConditionID = reader.GetString(5);
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(6))                      
                            temp.StartDate = reader.GetDateTime(6);                                                                          
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
                        temp.StatusDate = reader.GetDateTime(7);
                    if (temp.DueDate <= temp.StartDate)
                        temp.DueDate = temp.StartDate.AddMonths(18);                        
                    FCConditionsList.Add(temp);
                }
            }
```

The one that is throwing the error is while reading in the StartDate (reader.GetDateTime(6)). I have tried storing it in a var and bringing it w/ reader.GetOracleDate and reader.GetValue and they all still throw the same error.

The Datetime I'm trying to read in has a value of: 6/7/2017 5:16:41 PM
I've included a screen shot of the watch tool in the state right before it tries to read in that column[image]

Comment: I think the columns 6 & 7 may be reversed.  The error should occur on DueDate since it is null.

Comment: @jdweng If that were the case, it should just skip over that line of code since I have the DBNull check, right?

Comment: As you get closer to creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will find out why your posted code is throwing an exception. You can either start with a function that creates a reader based upon "select sysdate from dual" or you can start cutting out code in your existing function.

Comment: Net will not allow a DateTime to be null.  Instead the default 1/1/01 is used for a DateTime in Net.  I'm not sure how Oracle works.

Comment: Are you absolutely, absolutely sure it is this line?  I know that Oracle is funny with numbers.  I am a little bit surprised that you are not getting an error with (3) and (4), where it is showing as decimal, but you seem to be able to read with GetInt32.  If you don't mind my asking, what is the Oracle datatype for these fields (I always use NUMBER(9,0) for .Net ints in Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `GetDateTime` call is not expecting the AM/PM symbol? As such it probably can't identify it as a valid date/time.  Try this:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(6)) {
  var temporaryDate = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();

  DateTime outDate;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(temporaryDate, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate))
  {
    temp.StartDate = outDate;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I faced the same issue myself today and solved it differently... I am using the Oracle Data access Managed Client

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(6)) {
  var tempDate = reader.GetOracleDate(6);
  temp.StartDate = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, tempDate.Day, tempDate.Hour, tempDate.Minute, tempDate.Second);
}
```

Comment: But it dealt with GetDateTime(2) and that had AM?  Also both are showing as object Sysem.DateTime.  So I don't think it can have anything to do with AM/PM?

Comment: was just a hunch, the GetDateTime(2) returned a different formatted date, easy to understand 12/31 - but dates that are 6/7 is anybody's guess...

Answer (score 0):

I was just fighting with this issue as well. In my case, I am reading a `DateTime?` field from an old Oracle DB and it is served to me as `dd MMM yy HH:mm` format, which trips my `C#` code.

My solution is as follows...

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
{
    CultureInfo enGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    var od = reader.GetString(7);

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(od, "dd MMM yy HH:mm", enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result))
    {
        theDateTimeValueYouNeed = result;
    }
}
```